# Rijndael: Same input / different output on multiple machines

Tags: c#, rijndael

Some software i wrote uses the Rijndael algorithm from .Net4.0 to encrypt and decrypt license information.

The Problem is as followed:
The program generates a string, which is transformed into a byte[]. This byte[] is then encrypted with Rijndael into another byte[] which is then transferred to other computers.
There, this encrypted byte[] is decrypted again and the resulting byte[] is transformed back again into a string to retrieve the information from it.

Basically this works perfectly fine ... but not that perfect i guess.

There is one computer in our office that seems to encrypt and decrypt in a different way.

If i try to decrypt the byte[] on another computer, it gives me something like that:

```
{"Zeichenabstände sind ungültig und können nicht entfernt werden."}
 bei System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.DecryptData(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount, Byte[]& outputBuffer, Int32 outputOffset, PaddingMode paddingMode, Boolean fLast)
 bei System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManagedTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
 bei System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
 bei System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
 bei System.IO.Stream.Close()
```

The code doing the encryption looks like this:

```
private byte[] EncryptBytes(byte[] originalBytes) {
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    Rijndael crypt = Rijndael.Create();
    crypt.Key = KeyBytes;
    crypt.IV = IVBytes;
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, crypt.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cs.Write(originalBytes, 0, originalBytes.Length);
    cs.Close();
    Byte[] cryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Close();
    return cryptedBytes;
}
```

For decryption it's the same, just with CreateDecryptor() instead of CreateEncryptor().

For testing and solving the problem, i did the following:

On both computers i encrypted exactly the same string.
I checked that this string is transformed into exactly the same byte[] on both machines.
The Rijndael object has the same property values on both machines so its configured the same way (Key, IV, Padding etc.)

The encrypted byte[] output afterwards is completely different on both machines.

This is where I'm stuck. I can't think of a reason for this behaviour and neither could the internet help me. Both computers run Windows XP x86 with .Net4.0

I am very gratefull for any hint and thank you in advance,
mls

Fun fact: It has worked fine on 12 different computers, machine 13 is bitching around :)

Comment: Did you make sure that chaining method (ex. Cipher Block Chaining) is set on all machines. Padding is important too.

Comment: Out of interest is the machine 13 on a different architecture (32 bit instead of 64 or vice versa)? Does this occur with all strings? do you notice anything with trivial strings (eg sending a single null byte)?

Comment: Verify that the byte arrays for key, IV, and ciphertext are identical on all machines. There might be some encoding issues that corrupt the data along the way.

Comment: Not directly related to your issue: Your IV use is probably wrong. You should choose a new, random IV each time you encrypt. Using a constant completely misses the point of an IV.

Answer (score 1):

The message means

```
Padding is invalid and cannot be removed
```

I'm guessing that the actual data being encrypted is different. If it is *supposed* to be the same, the difference could be in the encoding. I think system default encoding can vary, as will the system locale (System.Globalization.Culture and CurrentCulture).

Anyways, in one of the cases, the padding is incorrect. Rijndael input needs to be padded to certain sizes in order for encryption to be supported. You should check the documentation for Rijndael crypt.

Chances are, there is a flag you can use to have the input *automatically* be default-padded (take care of this when decrypting, because you will get the source + padding back, not just the source)

Comment: Padding is PKCS7 on all machines. The machines itself are x64 hardware with x86 os.

Comment: The data cannot be corrupted, i've been writing it into a textfile to compare both inputs and outputs. Both machines actually encrypt exactly the same byte[]. i'm currently testing with other strings to verify

Comment: Translating "Padding" as "Zeichenabstände" in this context is pretty weird. The German wikipedia uses "Padding" and "Füllbytes": http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding

Comment: @CodesInChaos I didn't make that up. I got the translation from google (search)

Comment: @mls How are you comparing the files? Prefer md5sum or similar, since the representation may be different, even with the same encoding and character sets

Comment: @mls Huh. What does Visual Studio have to do with anything? Also, please stay on topic.

Comment: the comparing is actually pretty simple. i append every bytevalue as a string to a .txt with StreamWriter.WriteLine(...
For quick comparing i use svn diff to check if the contents of both input files generated on the machines have defferences.

Comment: Okay, so you end up with a file containing `104, 101, 108, 108, 111` (e.g.) for ANSI/latin1 encoded 'hello'. That should do, I guess.

Comment: Alright, the solution for it was rather simple. Small strings have the ssame behaviour. The IV is generated from double to string values to create a more or less unpredictable IV. sehe was totally right about the culture settings. when every other computer generated its IV with a german-like , as decimal seperator, my colleague here uses . on his system. I should have checked the exact key and iv bytes earlier. But thanks for all your helpfull comments :)

Comment: @mls: more to the point you shouldn't have told us that the key and IV were the same for both in the question if you didn't confirm that. ;-) Glad you got it sorted though. :)

Comment: @sehe I didn't claim you made it up. Microsoft made up that weird German "translation". Guess they used machine translation.

Comment: @CodesInChaos yeah, I guess they somehow ended up using a term more appropriate to typography or graphical design :)